# getting "undefined method `url' for "":String" Using paperclip in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, e-commerce

I'm getting this error on the`app/views/cart/_cart.html.erb`page of an E-commerce app I'm building `undefined method 'url' for "":String
Did you mean?  URI`

If I exclude the line `<td><%= image_tag item.product.image.url(:thumb) %></td>` from the code I don´t get the messages and can see what is in the cart, but no small picture of the product in the cart.

It would be so nice if someone could help me out here since I'm a ROR newbie and can't figure it out on my own.

here is the `_cart.html.erb` view were the error is appearing

```
<% @cart.product_items.each do |item| %>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price &euro;</th>
        <th>Image</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.quantity %>&times; </td>
        <td><%= item.product.title %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price_usd, :unit => '€ ', :precision => 0)%></td>
        <td><%= image_tag item.product.image.url(:thumb) %></td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

The app has model for Images, and it looks like this:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product
  has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

end
```

And the `product.rb` model is like this

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list :scope => [:category, :label]
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :label

  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
  has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy

   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  #before_destroy :ensure_not_product_item

    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    validates :price_usd, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true

end
```

the `product_item.rb`model is like this:

```
class ProductItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product 
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :order

  belongs_to :image

  def total_price_usd
    product.price_usd * quantity
  end

end
```

I can see the product images in the `views/products/show` but when I have added a product to the cart and want to take a look at the items in the cart the app breaks with the error messages: `undefined method 'url' for "":String
Did you mean?  URI`

here is the `views/products/show.html.erb`

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 center-block" >
      <div id='carousel-custom' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
        <div class='carousel-outer'>
            <!--slider -->
            <div class='carousel-inner '>
                <div class='item active'>
                    <%= image_tag @product.images.first.image.url(:medium), 
                     class: "img-responsive", id: "" %>
                    </div>      
                    <% @product.images.drop(1).each do |image_product| %>
                       <div class='item'>
                        <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), 
                        class: "img-responsive", id: "" %>

              </div>
                <% end %>

            <script>
              $("#zoom_05").elevateZoom({ zoomType    : "inner", cursor: 
              "crosshair" });
            </script>
        </div>
        <!-- sag sol -->
        <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-
         slide='prev'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
        </a>
        <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-
         slide='next'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
        </a>
    </div>
                <!-- thumb -->
    <ol class='carousel-indicators mCustomScrollbar meartlab'>
        <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='0' class='active'>
            <%= image_tag @product.images.first.image.url(:medium), class: 
         "img-responsive", id: "zoom_05" %>
        </li>
        <% @product.images[1..-1].each_with_index do |image_product, index| 
           %>
            <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to=<%= index + 1%> 
             >
                <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-
              responsive", id: "" %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
        </li>
    </ol>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".mCustomScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar({axis:"x"});
    });
   </script>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `has_many :images` in `Product`. And `Image` model has attached file named **image**. So first you should fetch **all images of a product** with `product.images`, loop through each image and map the image url like below

```
#fetch all images of a product
<% item.product.images.each do |img| %>
  #map the url of each img
  <td><%= image_tag img.image.url(:thumb) %></td>
<% end %>
```

where `img` is an instance of `Image` and `image` is **attached file name**.

Having the **file name(image)** same as **model name(image)** will confuse things(as it did now). To keep things simple in the future, try a different name. For example, say **avatar**, then the above code would look like below

```
#fetch all images of a product
<% item.product.images.each do |img| %>
  #map the url of each img
  <td><%= image_tag img.avatar.url(:thumb) %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: in the loop it should be ```image_tag img.image.url(:thumb)``` not ```image_tag item.product.img.image.url(:thumb)```

Comment: thank you guys, this is working, but showing all images for the product as a :thumb,  what if I only want to show one image for the product in the cart? I tried to add `.first` to the line like : `<td><%= image_tag img.first.image.url(:thumb) %></td>` but that gave me the error: `undefined method 'first' for #<Image:0x007faa06be8ab8>`

Comment: @codegirl If you want show only one image, then just do `<%= image_tag item.product.images.first.image.url(:thumb) %>` in your original code.

Comment: Of course @Pavan, thank you so much for your help, this is all working now